# Add a new column in dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset which looks like this:
[image]

I need to add a column "forgets" which would distinguish if there were more than 2 wrong hits, the it should contain "yes", and if less than or equal to 2 attempts, then "no"

I am grouping first, and then trying to add "yes" and "no" values

```
library(dplyr)
p <- group_by(d,  Participant, Session, Condition, Block, PassedIconName)

for (i in 1:nrow(p)){
  if (p$WrongHitsCount[i] >2){
    p$Forget[i] <- "yes"
  } else {
    p$Forget[i] <-"no"
  }
}
```

But this code puts "yes" to the first attempts of the datafile, and for the rest, it puts "no". I need to have "no" in all the instances for an icon that was hit incorrectly more than 2 times.

Could you please tell me how it can be achieved?

Comment: What is the `group_by` supposed to do in this code?

Comment: to group the rows and consider them as 1 item @liborm

Comment: Please include the image directly in the post, or even better paste the output of `dput(d)`, se people can try their code before posting.

Comment: Why not just `p$Forget <- ifelse(p$WrongHitsCounts > 2, "yes", "no")`?

Comment: @Heroka because OP needs the groups, how do you do the groups like this?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the text that well and the code doesn't show a grouped operation. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Stick to `dplyr`;)

```
d %>%
  mutate(forgets = ifelese(WrongHitsCount > 2, "yes", "no")) ->
  dmod
```

Or if you want to do it by the groups. Your simple for loop won't obey the `group_by`. It's not really clear in the question what kind of aggregation you want to do, so I used the `> 2` condition for each row separately (alternatively you may e.g. want to sum the wrong hits and then compare with 2):

```
d %>%
  mutate(condition_hit = WrongHitsCount > 2) %>%
  group_by(Participant, Session, Condition, Block, PassedIconName) %>%
  summarise(condition_hit = sum(condition_hit)) %>%
  mutate(forgets = ifelese(condition_hit > 1, "yes", "no")) %>%
  select(-condition_hit) ->
  dmod
```

Comment: Technically, you don't need dplyr for this.

Comment: @Heroka Technically, you can do it in the excel sheet manually;)

Comment: Technically, you are using three lines of code for something that can be achieved in one. I'm all for legibility and group_by_dostuff packages, but sometimes base-R really is easier/more legible/uses less code.

Comment: @Heroka I'm paid for the characters I type;) No, really, legibility is the king, you write the code once and read it many times. I used to do all the `sapply`, `lapply`, `tapply`, `mapply` magic, but I'm through with it. I like how clear are your intentions in `dplyr` vocabulary, I like the left-to-right data flow which I can achieve here easily, I like how it plays well with `ggplot`...

Comment: @Heroka my dataset is huge, i just pasted a screenshot here, so doing it in excel would be very painful.